# I used os.system("start audio.mp3") in python and it worked. But it does not close itself and the audio opens on other screens

Tags: python, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, os.system, google-text-to-speech

I open the audio file but it does not close itself and the player opens on other screens. How can I open it minimized. Then I want it to close itself.

```
from gtts import gTTS
import os

def speech():
   language = 'tr'
   myText = "Welcome"
   output = gTTS(text=myText, lang=language, slow=False)
   output.save("audio.mp3")
   os.system("start audio.mp3")
   time.sleep(5)
   os.system("close audio.mp3")
.
.
.
speech()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`playsound`](https://pypi.org/project/playsound/) package offers a simple utility that can be used to open -> play -> close .mp3 files with Python. It's quite handy and does not open a new window or require you to force the interpreter to wait until the file has finished playing.

[`playsound`](https://pypi.org/project/playsound/) describes itself as a *Pure Python, cross platform, single function module with no dependencies for playing sounds*, and can be installed by running.

```sh
pip install playsound
```

Below code has been tested and seems to work quite well for your use case.

```py
from gtts import gTTS
from playsound import playsound

def speech():
   language = 'tr'
   myText = "Welcome"
   output = gTTS(text=myText, lang=language, slow=False)
   output.save("audio.mp3")
   playsound('audio.mp3')
   
speech()
```

Comment: Playsound meets my needs , it worked for me .Thanks